# Session Problem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that times out the session after 20 minutes. I store some values for a dropdown in a Session variable. If a user allows a page to timeout and then refreshes the page, I have no values in the dropdown.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Persist the information into some form of storage e.g. a Database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the dropdown data is from a database. If so, you'll need to repopulate the session. I assume you are using Windows authentication - otherwise, say if you were using form-based authentication, you would also have to get the user to log in again by redirecting to a login page.

If the dropdown data is not from a database, you could store it in Web.config and update it from there.

Exactly how you deal with this depends on specifics which you haven't mentioned. For example, on some of my projects, it's been sufficient to check if the session variable exists (on every non-post access to the page) and if absent, repopulate the session with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use InMemory cache instead of Session (if it's really needed to store it somewhere and do not get from database). You need just to specify key (for each dd list) and expiration time

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;

        public static dynamic Get(string key)
        {
                ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
                var item = cache.Get(key);
                return item;
        }

        public static void Put(string key, dynamic ddResult)
        {
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1); // expiration in one minute
                ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
                cache.Set(key, ddResult, policy);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Can I know whether it's a Windows application or a web-based application in the web-based application if you are going to use the database as source to display the data in the dropdown we give it as :

```
DropDownList3.DataSource = Class2.details().Tables[0];
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

Here `Class2` is the class having the function name called details in that we are going to have the SQL query to display the data from the database to the dropdown (`SELECT` query).

Then we will using that dropdownlist's data into the session as

```
session["anyname"]=dropdownlist3.selecteditem.text;
```

Then according to you we can give the timeout values in the `web.config` file also.